# cf push is failing while deploying my java code

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have code residing in my local machine ( windows), and I am trying to deploy it with CLI. 
I successfully logged into the bluemix but while entering cf push command it is giving following error :

NO org and space targeted, use 'cf target -o ORG -s SPACE' to target and org and space.

I am not sure how shall I proceed here, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to run the command specified, filling in values for ORG and SPACE.

ORG is most likely the same as your email address you logged in with, and SPACE is most likely "dev".  So if your email is bob@example.org, the command to run is:

```
cf target -o bob@example.org -s dev
```

There's some information on CloudFoundry orgs and spaces here: http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/roles.html

Answer (score 0):

One similar issue is already addressed by Bluemix support:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/166972/no-org-and-space-targeted-use-cf-target-o-org-s-sp.html

If issue is coming while running cf push...can you provide the logs generated using

"cf logs app_name --recent"